# How to automatical update html table by clicking the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am JavaScript/html beginner and currently I am dealing with following issue:
I have several input fields, which are filled by the user. 
When he filled up the fields, he presses the button and several tables are created.
So far works everything fine.
BUT

If I update the information in the input field and press the button, the NEW tables are created (the previous tables stay and new are added below)

My idea was to make following:
I put the new tables in a separate div.
Every time I press the button, the div information is deleted and created again.
But as I am a beginner I don’t really know how to do it.

Can anyone help me?

Do you have a better idea?

My code
(...)

/*part with the table creation*/

```
var zaehler=0;
for (zaehler = 0; zaehler < n; zaehler++){

tableCreate(n,zaehler,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l);

    }}
```

/*the table create function*/`

```
<script>
    function tableCreate(maxyear,s4italka, a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l) {

    var imena  = ["Выручка", "Управляющая кампания", "Профилактика", "Налог на Недвижимость", "Страховка", "Амортизация", "Тело кредита", "%-ные выплаты банку", "%-ные выплаты себе", "Доход",
    "Налог (15%)", "Финансовый результат" ];

    var dannie =[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l];



        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var tbl = document.createElement('table');
        tbl.style.width = '40%';
        tbl.setAttribute('border', '1');
        var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
        var trh = document.createElement('tr');
        var th = document.createElement('th');
        var m=s4italka+2015;
        th.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Результат на '+m+ ' год'))
        th.setAttribute ('colSpan','2');
        trh.appendChild(th)
        tbdy.appendChild(trh);
        for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {



                    var td = document.createElement('td');
                    if ((j % 2) != 0) 
                    {td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dannie[i]))}
                    else {
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(imena[i]))}

                    tr.appendChild(td)

            }

            tbdy.appendChild(tr);
        }
        tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
        body.appendChild(tbl)
       var p= document.createElement('p');
       body.appendChild(p);


    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the previous table first. Currently the code that you have keeps appending new table to the body only but all the previous elements still remain there.

To remove the previous table:

jQuery:

```
body.find("table").remove();
```

Javascript:

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
    tables[i].remove();
}
```

You can insert the code above before the line `body.appendChild(tbl)`

Note: jQuery function `remove()` will not throw error even if the table does not exist at the time of executing the code.

Comment: OP doesn't seem to use jQuery anywhere. I see the tag in question BUT i guess it is wrongly/abusively used

Comment: 1) thank you very much for help  
2) i do use jquery but just in another part :)
3) the question might be stupid but still:
To arrange all my inputfields i am using a table. So when i use the suggested for iteration, th input field table is also deleted. 
I will change the table to div fragment with css, but for my understanding, why does not this code work ?  

var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
for (var i = 1; i < tables.length; i++) {
    tables[i].remove();
}

Answer (score 0):

```
 function tableCreate(maxyear, s4italka, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l) {


       var imena = ["Выручка", "Управляющая кампания", "Профилактика", "Налог на Недвижимость", "Страховка", "Амортизация", "Тело кредита", "%-ные выплаты банку", "%-ные выплаты себе", "Доход",
       "Налог (15%)", "Финансовый результат"];

       var dannie = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l];


       $('.myTabel').remove();
       var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
       var tbl = document.createElement('table');
       $(tbl).addClass('myTabel');
       tbl.style.width = '40%';
       tbl.setAttribute('border', '1');
       var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
       var trh = document.createElement('tr');
       var th = document.createElement('th');
       var m = s4italka + 2015;
       th.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Результат на ' + m + ' год'))
       th.setAttribute('colSpan', '2');
       trh.appendChild(th)
       tbdy.appendChild(trh);
       for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
           var tr = document.createElement('tr');
           for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {



               var td = document.createElement('td');
               if ((j % 2) != 0)
               { td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dannie[i])) }
               else {
                   td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(imena[i]))
               }

               tr.appendChild(td)

           }

           tbdy.appendChild(tr);
       }
       tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
       body.appendChild(tbl)
       var p = document.createElement('p');
       body.appendChild(p);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but your variant shows me only one last table

Comment: Do u want to append the content at the end?